# How to convolve two audio signal?

Tags: sound, signal-processing, convolution

Can we obtain reverb effect by convolve two audio signal?
Here are some example.

https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1vE411h7W2

Comment: Can we achieve in mathematica?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yes. Look at ListConvolve and/or RecurrenceFilter.